# How to add to array in main?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have created an array which I wanted to control from main. My code runs, but I don't know how to add integers to the array from the main class. Also as each ConcreteSubject has its own storage array, how would i change this to store them all in the same array?

```
public class ConcreteSubject extends AbstractSpy
{
    private AbstractSpy[] spies = new AbstractSpy[10];
    private int i = 0;

    public void addSpy(AbstractSpy s) {
        if (i < spies.length) {
            spies[i] = s;
            System.out.println("spy added at index " + i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject();
        AbstractSpy spies = new AbstractSpy() {
            @Override
            public void addSpy(AbstractSpy spies) {
            }
        };

        cs.addSpy(cs);
        spies.addSpy(spies);
    }
}
```

Comment: `spies.addSpy(spies);` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: You'll want to clear up your types as a start: 'TestClass' should by 'SpyTester' (say).
And 'ConcreteSubject' should be 'ConcreteSpy'.  But that is probably not enough: If there will be a collection of spies, having a 'Spies' class (to hold the spies), and having a different type for individual spies (AbstractSpy and ConcreteSpy) would be a better object decomposition.

Comment: Can't understand your use case completely. You are extending a class as well as holding the array of same class and that is not correct use of inheritance. Name `AbstractSpy` suggests it is an `Abstract` class but you are creating an object. Please elaborate more about your use case.

Comment: Note that the storage array 'spies' in 'ConcreteSubject' is declared as an instance variable.  That means that each 'ConcreteSubject' has its own storage array, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I know that, but i didn't design the use case which is why i am confused as well.  Basically I am trying to create an array in ConcreteSubject which i can add to in TestClass. It adds ints from parameters, which i know i havent done. I'm not sure how to go about doing this?

Comment: @ThomasBitonti No that's not what i want. How do you store each ConcreteSubject in the same array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your program logic is a little borked. This bit in particular doesn't make much sense:

```
        ***AbstractSpy spies = new AbstractSpy() {
            @Override
            public void addSpy(AbstractSpy spies) {
            }
        };

        cs.addSpy(cs);
        ***spies.addSpy(spies);
```

What you're doing is creating TWO AbstractSpy instances, one named `cs` and one named `spies`. On that last line you're adding `spies` to itself! That doesn't help you at all.

Note that `AbstractSpy` is the most granular unit in your setup - it shouldn't have an `addSpy()` method and its own internal array,  it should be the thing that's *added* to something *else's* array!

Here's the same code, but cleaned up a bit:

```
public abstract class AbstractSpy { }
public class ConcreteSpy extends AbstractSpy { }

public class ConcreteSubject {
    private AbstractSpy[] spies = new AbstractSpy[10];
    private int i = 0;

    public void addSpy(AbstractSpy spy) {
        if (i < spies.length)
        {
            spies[i] = spy;
            System.out.println("spy added at index " + i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject();
        AbstractSpy spy = new ConcreteSpy();
        cs.addSpy(spy);
    }
}
```

The big difference here is that `ConcreteSpy` is an implementation of `AbstractSpy` that you can add to your `ConcreteSubject`'s array of spies. I think you might have been confused by Java's insistence that you can't create an instance of an abstract class on its own unless you supply an anonymous class that inherits from the abstract class.

Comment: Ahh! thank you for this, makes so much more sense now! How would you add an integer to the array in the main class though?

Comment: @JayMac Glad it helped! I'm not sure what you mean though. Your code doesn't have an array in the `TestClass` - the array you're storing stuff in is in the `ConcreteSubject` class. The array is also only for `AbstractSpy`-type objects - you can't add an integer to that array. You can create a new `static int[]` array in `TestClass` that you can add integers to if you want - I'm confused about what you're trying to do though. Hope that helps you get further.